# Prove the inequality involving exponential function in form of $\exp( \frac{1}{x} )$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, rational-functions

For $\nu > 0$, $0 < x \leq \nu $, and a positive integer $S$,
(we think) following an inequality always holds

$1- \left( \frac{1}{x+1} \right)^S \geq \exp \left( -\frac{1}{Sx}  \right) $

Does anyone help us for proving it?

Comment: Any thoughts on the solution below?

Comment: We think it is correct! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $S=1$, we have
$$
\exp(1/x)\geq 1+1/x=\frac{x+1}{x}\iff\exp(-1/x)\leq\frac{x}{1+x}=1-\frac{1}{x+1}.
$$
Suppose that the claim is true for some $S\geq 1$. Then, we have
$$
\exp(S/x)\geq[1-(1/(x+1))^S]^{-1}\quad\text{and}\quad\exp(1/x)\geq[1-1/(x+1)]^{-1}.
$$
Multiplying these inequalities, we have
$$
\exp[(S+1)/x]\geq [1-(1/(x+1))^S]^{-1}[1-1/(x+1)]^{-1}
$$
So it suffices to show
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^S}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\leq\left(1-\frac{1}{(x+1)^{S+1}}\right).\tag{$*$}
$$
But this is true: for ($*$),
$$
\text{RHS}-\text{LHS}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^{S+1}}\left[(x+1)^S-1+x\right]>0.
$$
(For the term in the square brackets above, one can for example use the Bernoulli's inequality $(x+1)^S-1+x\geq xS+1-1+x=x(S+1)>0$.)

Comment: I think it is correct.
Our approach was based on showing 'quasi-concave' of RHS - LHS (original inquality), but we had some problem.
Thank you for your comments & proof!